# Create Multiple Event Calendars

Tags: datetime

I use the Event Calendar on my site. I have a request to have a separate calendar for each department. Is this possible with in the same site?

If so please share the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the department id in the url and then use it as as a contextual filter in the same view.

Check out https://drupal.org/node/1578558

> Contextual filters work similarly to regular filters, but there is one
>   important difference. Instead of setting a filter value manually, the
>   value is fetched from variables sent programmatically to the view.

Comment: I wish i could understand this since im a drupal newbie.

Comment: What is your Department? Is it a taxonomy term?

Comment: I have a Site wide Event Calendar using (event Calendar). Department is just another page that is accesible only by certain group and they will need to update their own calendar that is separate from the main calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a personal calendar you need - for each individual or for a group.

For an individual settings are like this (nevermind the entity reference fields). Important fields are highlighted. In this calendar a user can only see his own events

[image]

or for a group calendar where only members of the groups can see events - use the settings below.

[image]

Nodeone.se do great screencasts if you want to learn about either views or organic groups.
Hope this helps.

You also need a groups audience field in your event form.
[image]

Comment: The Calendar should be public but only certain group can update. But will show different data than the home page calendar.

Comment: Ah - that seems more like a permissions issue then. allowing members of the group to edit and create events and allowing all others to view events - maybe create a new event content type and calendar and then in people/permissions set up the permissions - the only issue there might be how to assign permissions to group members

Comment: Really the bottom line is can i create multiple different calendars across the site ?

Comment: yes you can....